# Meaning of sparse in "sparse cross entropy loss"?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cross-entropy

I [read](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#binarycrossentropy-class) from the documentation:

> ```
> tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
>     from_logits=False, reduction="auto", name="sparse_categorical_crossentropy"
> )
> ```
>
> Computes the crossentropy loss between the labels and predictions.
>
> Use this crossentropy loss function when there are two or more label
> classes. We expect labels to be provided as integers. If you want to
> provide labels using **one-hot** representation, please use
> `CategoricalCrossentropy` loss. There should be # classes floating point
> values per feature for `y_pred` and a single floating point value per
> feature for `y_true`.

Why is this called **sparse** categorical cross entropy? If anything, we are providing a more compact encoding of class labels (integers vs one-hot vectors).

Comment: it switches from integer (compact) to one-hot (sparse)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it's actually the opposite thus my confusion. The sparse version takes in the true labels as integers, whereas the non-sparse one takes in true labels as one-hot encoded vectors.

Comment: yes...It's only question of name... I think you understood the concept. would you like a practical example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because integer encoding is more compact than one-hot encoding and thus more suitable for encoding sparse binary data. In other words, integer encoding = better encoding for sparse binary data.

This can be handy when you have many possible labels (and samples), in which case a one-hot encoding can be significantly more wasteful than a simple integer per example.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly it is called like that is probably best answered by Keras devs. However, note that this sparse cross-entropy is *only* suitable for "sparse labels", where exactly one value is 1 and all others are 0 (if the labels were represented as a vector and not just an index).

On the other hand, the general `CategoricalCrossentropy` also works with targets that are not one-hot, i.e. any probability distribution. The values just need to be *between* 0 and 1 and sum to 1. This tends to be forgotten because the use case of one-hot targets is so common in current ML applications.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm confused, from what I gather both versions only accept as **true labels** for the loss a set of categorical choices that are either one-hot encoded or integers. This would make sense to me as they are **categorical** cross entropies after all. However, are you saying that, in fact, the `CategoricalCrossEntropy` loss function accepts vectors with real positive values for the **true label** argument?

Comment: Yes -- it measures the cross entropy between two categorical probability distributions. Such distributions assign _probabilities_ to a set of discrete categories, but probabilities can be between 0 and 1 -- they don't have to be hard 0s and 1s. As such, the `label` can be _any categorical probability distribution_ (just like the predictions are usually soft probabilities, gotten from a softmax layer). Check equation 1 on the Wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy No need for p or q to be one-hot!

Comment: This answer is wrong. As the Keras [docs](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#sparsecategoricalcrossentropy-class) point out, `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` expects labels to be provided as integers. This is not a sparse representation of the data, hence the OP's question.

Also, as the [docs](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class) further indicate, `CategoricalCrossentropy` expects targets to be one-hot encoded. You cannot pass targets with values in the range 0-1. 

It may not be mathematically necessary but Keras requires this.

Comment: 1. Actually, providing integers of those positions that are non-0 is _exactly_ what a sparse representation is. 2. Yes, `CategoricalCrossentropy` works on any probability distribution, not just one-hot targets. Have you actually _tried_ it? Note we are talking about `tf.keras` here, I don't know about "standalone" Keras.